# Absolute expiration and sliding expiration are not working(caching)

Tags: asp.net

// guys please help the absolute caching and sliding caching are not working i am unable to find where is the problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Caching;

namespace WebApplication154
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string cs = 
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString;
```

code to bind grid view when the page is loading

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblserver.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        DataSet ds = getdata();
        Cache["products"] = ds;
        grid1.DataSource = ds;
        grid1.DataBind();

    }
```

i am passing data from database to dataset

```
    public DataSet getdata()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spfrag", conn);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
```

the data is not caching even i mentioned the below code

```
    protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Cache["products"] != null)
        {
            DataSet ds = (DataSet)Cache["products"];
            grid1.DataSource = ds;
            grid1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            DataSet ds = getdata();
            Cache.Add("products", ds, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
            grid1.DataSource = ds;
            grid1.DataBind();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: How/when do you see that the Cache isn't used? For debugging that 20 sec timeout may be too short.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try pulling from the cache in `getdata()` and only pull from the database if the cache is empty there.  Check out the Cache Repository Pattern for an [example](https://ardalis.com/introducing-the-cachedrepository-pattern)

The way this coded now you would only ever pull from the cache on the second `btnsubmit_Click` event fire.  You would end up going to the database on every `Page_Load` too, which fires on `btnsubmit_Click` too.